# Relationship between $f(x)=\frac1x$ and $g(x) = \ln|x|+C$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to understand the relationship between the function $f$ and its derivative function $g$, or in other words, $g$ and its antiderivative $f$.

Here is what i understand: the graph of function $g$ plots the tangents of the graph of function $f$ to $x$ input.

If i am not wrong: the graph of function $f$ plots the area under graph of function $g$ to $x$, where $x$ is the lower bound of the area under the graph $g$.

Now, given $g(x) = \frac1x$ and $f(x) = \ln |x|+C$, i plot both graphs using Desmos: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKeDh.jpg

Graph of function g does indeed map the slopes of tangents of function $f$ at each $x$ value. However, the area under graph of function $g$ is clearly not mapped by graph of function $f$: when $X > 0$, area under graph of function $g$ is always +ve, but graph of function $f$ will always give some -ve output. Why is this so?

I would greatly appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 2):

If $f = g'$, then the Fundmental Theorem of Calculus says that
$$\int_a^b f = g(b) - g(a).$$
Note that subtracting these values will remove the free parameter $C$.

Basically, what I'm saying is that the anti-derivative doesn't just give you the area, but the **change in value** in the anti-derivative will give you the (signed) area under the curve.

It's also worth noting that the derivative doesn't really plot the *tangent* line per se, but plots the gradient of the tangent line at the given $x$ value.

Comment: Thank you. Just to confirm: for the graph g', i am right in thinking that graph of g' maps area under graph of f (bounded from a certain x to another larger x value and the graph of f)? If so, could you explain this: given g(x) = 1/x and f(x) = ln|x|+C, i plot both graphs using Desmos: https://imgur.com/a/wMuwSC7? The graph g does not seem to map the area under graph f. Appreciate it.

Comment: You can always get a family of anti-derivatives by considering $x \mapsto \int_a^x f$, by varying $a$. In particular, $\ln(x)$ is given by $\int_1^x \frac{1}{x} \mathrm{d}x$ (in fact, in uni, we treated this as the *definition* of the natural logarithm). So, yes, the area under $1/x$, measured from the point $1$ to a point $x_0$, will be $\ln(x_0)$. Bear in mind (and this might be the source of your problem, $\int_1^x = -\int_x^1$, so considering $\ln(x)$ for $x < 1$ will produce a *negative* number, even though the graph lies above the axis.

Comment: Thank you so much Theo. If you don't mind, lets say $ \int_{0.01}^{0.99}\frac{1}{x} $, would this derivative be a negative or positive?

Comment: It's positive. The integrand $\frac{1}{x}$ is positive, and the lower bound $0.01$ is smaller than the upper bound $0.99$. Of course, $\int_{0.99}^{0.01} \frac{1}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x$ is negative, and the negative of the integral you've written.

Comment: Sorry for being dense, i am still trying to under the graphs i have (https://imgur.com/a/wMuwSC7). When you said 'so considering ln(x) for x<1 will produce a negative number, even though the graph lies above the axis'...i am still struggling to understand how g relates to f when x<1...any help there?

Comment: When $x < 1$, we have (as always) $\ln(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t.$ But, note how the upper bound is smaller than the lower bound! When you perform the subtraction $\ln(x) - \ln(1)$, you will be subtracting the greater quantity from the lesser, making a negative number. This negative number will be the **negative of the (positive) area under the curve, from $x$ to $1$**.

Comment: Thank you! I think i am getting it now :) One last question: why when x < 1, we have to use $\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{t}$ and not $\int_{x}^{1}\frac{1}{t}$?

Comment: Well, some might say that $\int_1^x \frac{1}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t$ is the definition of $\ln(x)$, which means $\int_x^1 \frac{1}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t = -\ln(x)$. Others might say, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $\int_x^1 \frac{1}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t = \ln(1) - \ln(x) = -\ln(x).$ Either way, you're getting the wrong answer.

Comment: Ahh, can i say: that for x<0, the graph of area under $\frac{1}{x}$ is bounded **from x=1** to a **x value smaller than 1** , and so for x<0, the area bounded are always -ve, due to the defintion of $\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{x}$, despite showing a positive area on the graph. So that is why $\int_{0.5}^{0.9}\frac{1}{x}$ is -ve, because $\int_{0.5}^{1}\frac{1}{x}$ (a larger negative value) minus $\int_{0.9}^{1}\frac{1}{x}$ (a smller negative value). Did i nail it?

Comment: Sorry, but maybe not quite. When you say $x < 0$, do you mean $x < 1$? If so, then I agree with the entire first sentence. But then $\int_{0.5}^{0.9} \frac{1}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t$ is actually positive (again, integrand is positive, and upper bound is greater than the lower bound). It's equal to $\ln(0.9) - \ln(0.5)$, which is positive since $\ln$ is an increasing function (this number is the area from $0.5$ to $0.9$). If you switch the numbers, you get $\ln(0.5) - \ln(0.9)$ which is negative, for the same reason (and is the negative of the aforementioned area)!

Comment: Oops, i do mean x < 1. I think i am getting there. One last question (promise): the y-axis of the antiderivative graph ln(x), what does it represent? ln(x1) - ln(x2) gives the area under graph 1/x bounded from x1 to x2, but ln(x1) in itself, what does it represent?

Comment: Well, since $\ln(1) = 0$, it represents the area under the graph from $1$ to $x$ if $x > 1$, or the negative of the area under the graph from $x$ to $1$ is $x < 1$. In general, the individual quantities of an anti-derivative don't represent much, since you can obtain another, equally valid antiderivative by adding some constant $C$.

Comment: Anyway, I'm off to bed. If you have further questions, I'll answer them tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you so very much! You have cleared so much of my doubts. Couldn't thank you enough.